# jni code in c++ is to be called in android studio

Tags: java, android, c++, java-native-interface

please help me correct this code so that it returns a string in MainActivity.java(Android studio-1.1.0,gradle-2.2.1) when getString12 is called there. I get an error getString12 not found? the library (.so) also gets generated. Can anyone say if anything is wrong with the code?

test.cpp

```
//#include "test.h"
#include <string.h>
#include <jni.h>
/*char* getString12();
char* Java_com_example_myapplication_Application_getString12()
{   char x[80]="Hello World!!!";
    char *s1 = new char [sizeof(x)];
     strcpy(s1,x);
     return s1;
}*/
extern "C" {
    JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_getString12(JNIEnv *env,
                                                     jobject obj)
   {
```

Which of the two shall i use? the commented 3 lines or the other 2 lines
 I have tried executing with both by alternate commenting and get the same error

```
 // char sk[30]="hello-world!!!";
//        const char *v = (const char *)sk;
//        return (*v)->NewStringUTF(env,"Hello from C++ JNI !");


         jstring x="hellllooooo!!!!";  
        return x;
    }
}


MainActivity.java
static{
        System.loadLibrary("gnustl_shared");
    }

    public native String getString12();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        TextView field = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        String f=getString12();
        field.setText(getString12());
```

The library is created in src/libs/armeabi/libgnustl_shared.so

Comment: How is the `getString12`-function declared in Java? And does the package part of the signature (`com_example_myapplication`) match the name of your package?

Comment: TextView field = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
 field.setText(getString12());     The java file is pressent in MyApplication2/app/src/main/java/MainActivity

Comment: It sounds to me like your package name is then `com.example.myapplication2` - if that's correct then you need to change the `getString12()`-function's signature to include the "2" in the name - `Java_com_example_myapplication2_MainActivity_getString12`.

Comment: sorry my fault my package is com.example.myapplication

Answer (score 0):

First of all, are you sure the .so is being loaded? If it is, then it sounds to me like you have a signature mis-match between what Java expects and what your C++ is offering. I think your code should look something like: <sub>(untested)</sub>

Java:

```
package com.example.myapplication;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    static {
        System.loadLibrary("yourlibraryname");
    }

    public native String getString12();

    // ...
    public void someFunction() {
        TextView field = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text);
        field.setText(getString12());
    }
    // ...
}
```

C++:

```
#include <jni.h>

extern "C" JNIEXPORT jstring JNICALL Java_com_example_myapplication_MainActivity_getString12(JNIEnv* env, jobject self) {
    return env->NewStringUTF("Hello from getString12()");
}
```

Comment: Yes, My code looks something like yours! I don't understand what you mean when you say .so is loaded. A .so file gets created in the libs folder. I want to test if that .so library is working or not.

Comment: Let's use a slightly stretched analogy: Imagine you have a book, let's call it `yourlibrary`. You put it on the table next to your friend Java, and ask him to explain chapter `getString12` to you. He has never read the book, and has no way to answer your question, so you tell him to first open the book using `System.loadLibrary("yourlibrary")`. He does, and reads the index, and now he knows what (and where) `getString12` is, and will happily tell you all about it next time you ask.

Comment: wow! thnxx for the lovely explanation. I did the same i have added how my java part looks! Please have a look at it.